Ubuntu 24.04 virtual machine on VMWARE ESXI very slow
I installed a virtual machine on an IBM server with a fair share of computing power using VMWARE ESXI. The virtual machine has Ubuntu 24.04 as guest OS and has allocated 100 GB of RAM and 12 vCPUs.
I could not allocate more than 32 MB VRAM without having issues with the virtual machine.
Now when I boot it up I log into the standard Ubuntu desktop. If I use the console or Firefox everything runs reasonably smoothly, but as soon as I try to open a folder or the settings the machine grinds to an almost halt and becomes incredibly slow.
This seems a "graphical" problem, as cd-ing in a folder from the console runs with zero issues.
Any suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Try reducing the RAM and number of vCPU's as an experiment. As a first test, 16 GB RAM and 8 vCPU's would be a good start. If that gives an improvement, you at least have a basis for further optimization.

You allocated 100GB of memory to a single VM? Does Ubuntu 24.04 even support that much memory?  Your performance problems might be linked to the amount of memory you have allocated, if the host itself, does not have enough memory reserved to handle the VM.  However, I suspect the real problem, is connected to only allocating 32MB of VRAM. What version of ESXi?

Try and switch off "Accelerate 3D graphics" on Display section of VM Hardware settings. If that helps, then try looking for updated drivers like in the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1516008/883853

I've switched off 3D acceleration and upped VRAM to 128 MB. Performance has markedly improved and I can open folders with a reasonable speed. I found out something else, though: if I try to increase the video ram above the amount I've set, it throws a "invalid configuration for device '0'" error.
